# Sort by last character of input, then by preceding number?

Tags: sort

I have a file that looks like this:

```
foo03a
foo02b
quux01a
foo01a
foo02a
foo01b
foo03b
quux01b
```

I'd like it ordered by the last character (so `a` and `b` appear together) and then by the preceding number, and then by the prefix (though this is not essential). So that it results in:

```
foo01a
quux01a
foo02a
foo03a
foo01b
quux01b
foo02b
foo03b
```

It actually doesn't particularly matter where `quux01a` and `quux01b` appear, as long as they're in the relevant group -- they can appear as shown, before `foo01b`, or after `foo03b`.

Why? These are server names used in a blue/green deployment, so I want the 'A' servers together, then the 'B' servers.

I found the `-k` switch to GNU sort, but I don't understand how to use it to specify a particular character, counting from the end of the string.

I tried `cat foos | rev | sort | rev`, but that sorts `foo10a` and `foo10b` (when we count up that far) into the wrong place.

Comment: cat foos |rev | sort |rev
foo01a
foo02a
foo03a
foo01b
foo02b
foo03b

this is what I'm getting. Isn't it what you want ?

Comment: `sort -k1.6 -k1.4,1.5n -k1.1,1.3 file`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using GNU `awk`'s `match` function:

```
cat foos | \
  gawk 'match($0, /([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)/, a) {print a[3], a[2], $0}' | \
  sort | cut -d' ' -f3
```

The `gawk` command uses regex captures to generate the sort key, so that I end up with the following:

```
a 03 foo03a
b 02 foo02b
```

...etc.

Run that through `sort`, `cut` for the fields I want. Done.

Comment: `awk` doesn't need `cat`, just so you know. I'd use something like `sed 's/\(.*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1\x02\2\x02/' infile | sort -t $'\002' -k3,3 -k2,2n -k1,1 | tr -d $'\002'` here.

Comment: can also be done with any version of `sed`, using basic regular expressions: `sed -e 's/\(^[^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\+\)\(.\)$/\3 \2 \1\2\3/' foos | sort | cut -d' ' -f3`

Comment: Yes, I know that `awk` doesn't need `cat`. The actual list is generated from a `jq` query...

Answer (score 2):

You can `sort` by character position (indicated by number after `.`) of field (here field 1):

```
sort -k1.6 -k1.4,1.5n -k1.1,1.3 file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo03a
foo02b
foo01a
foo02a
foo01b
foo03b

$ sort -k1.6 -k1.4,1.5n -k1.1,1.3 file.txt 
foo01a
foo02a
foo03a
foo01b
foo02b
foo03b
```

---

Reverse way, using `rev`:

```
$ rev file.txt | sort -k1.1,1.1 -k1.2,1.3n -k1.4 | rev
foo01a
foo02a
foo03a
foo01b
foo02b
foo03b
```

Comment: That's character position from the start of the string, right? I need character position from the end. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Yes..you just need `rev` then..

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Check my edits..

Comment: Hmm. That sorts `foo10a` (etc.) into the wrong place...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Yes, it does..i think your best bet would be go with the first one (if you can)..